# NotificationChannel always make sound in Android 8.0

Tags: android, notification-channel

I have upgraded `target build version` to `27` so need to implement `notification channel`. I'm starting a foreground `service` which will show a notification when started. With notification channel it's working as expected but it's always `make sound`. Changing the notification `priority` doesn't have any effect.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
            CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    notification = new Notification.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("My App")
            .setContentText(status)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
}
```

I have checked `IMPORTANCE_MIN`, `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` and `IMPORTANCE_LOW`, all are making sound

Comment: Maybe you can check the settings for that channel and see if has any sound or not. Android O enables to configure any notification the way you want, changing the default values set by developers. Just double check this in case that you modified the default settings.

Comment: there is a method  setSound(Uri, Atrributes). If I call setSound(null,null) then notification doesn't show, if I call setSound(null,attributes) then notification appear with sound (default notification sound)

Comment: Just in case, remember that once the notification channel has been created for the first time, you cannot change the importance anymore. Calling createNotificationChannel with a different importance will have no effect. You need to clear the app data or uninstall the app in order to remove the channel and create it again.

Comment: @jmart That's the case :) If you already call createNotificationChannel with specific priority, you cannot change it without uninstall the app. In my case I run the app with priority default. It was making sound so I reduce the priority to LOW. But that settings was never applied until I uninstall the app. Please post your comment as answer, I will mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the notification channel has been created, it's not possible to change the importance anymore.

You need to clear the app data or uninstall the app in order to remove the channel and create it again with a different importance level.